# Export local Git changes into some diff file for viewing externally

Tags: git, git-diff, git-stash, git-difftool

What's the best way in Git to save my local changes into some file format so that others can review it before I make the commit? I know one way to do this is to use `git stash save -p` and others can view the patch file. However, I was wondering if there's a better way, for example something like this would be nice:

`git diff save > myfile`

Comment: Why not just commit and then format-patch? You can always modify the commit later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think local branch can be used in your scenario, which is also a significant advantage of git.

Saying you are working on `master` branch, just create a new branch called `dev`, do your work and commit as you wish on `dev` branch. If you want to send your local changes to others, just `git diff` the two branches and send out the results. Or you can even let others to pull your `dev` to have a review.

```
git diff master dev > myfile.diff
```

And if you want to push your changes to a remote central repository, just merge `dev` back to `master` and push. Git will help you do most of the work in the process.

PS. you guys may try some code review system integrated with git well such as [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org/) which is really fantastic and convenient.

Comment: is there any way to open the previously saved .diff file in an external tool such as Meld or Kdiff3?